# html(), children() and array pointer on found nodes don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to get text ("`content`") from two `<button>content</button/>` elements with enzyme but it doesn't work as expected:

```
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

let component = mount(<Form/>);

console.log(toJson(component.find('.form-postback .tokens button'))); 
// returns [{el #1}, {el #2}] - OK!

console.log(toJson(component.find('.form-postback .tokens button')[0])); 
// returns undefined - expected {el #1}

console.log(toJson(component.find('.form-postback .tokens button').at(0))); 
// returns {el #1} - OK!

console.log(toJson(component.find('.form-postback .tokens button').at(0).html())); 
// returns undefined - expected to get "content"

console.log(toJson(component.find('.form-postback .tokens button').at(0).children()));
// returns '' (empty string) - expected to get "content"
```

**Why `[0]` and `at(0).html()` return `undefined`?**

Comment: Maybe that `toJSON()` thing refuses to even try to serialize a DOM element, because they're generally problematic in that regard.

Comment: you're right, removing `toJson` from the line with `[0]` didn't seem to make a difference, but it worked for `at(0).html()`! so I can grab the content by `at(0).text()`